# Why cant i change the the current folder to a shared drive through Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a slave windows xp whos workspace directory I have changed to a shared folder that is on the master. It is able to pull the code from my repo, but when I try to access the shared workspace directory Jenkins just stays in the c:\windows directory. I tried using "cd ..", and switching drives "F:" (f is the shared drive i added as network drive). When doing 'F:' it gives me "The system cannot find the drive specified.".
Is there a line I am missing somewhere that forces the pipeline to work in the c:\windows directory? How would I go about leaving this directory?
PS I tried using  'pushd' and 'popd'

Answer (score 0):

Although I already did `net use F:` on the slave PC, it does not consider it as set.

To solve this, use the command

```
bat 'net use F: \\\\YOU_SHARED_FOLDER_IP_HERE\\shared_folder /u:user  /persistent:yes'
```

…in the first step of your pipeline where you are going to actually use the drive.

This will set the drive for Jenkins. After setting it one time, you can remove the `bat` command as you will be able to use the shared drive now.